# Coroutine is a class in its nature?

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

I am following an instruction to learn coroutine

```
def grep(pattern):
    print("Looking for %s" % pattern)  # prime it(explain shortly)
    while True:
        line = (yield) # expression
        if pattern in line:
            print(line)
```

Test it

```
>>> g = grep("python")
>>> g.next()
Looking for python
>>> g.send("coroutine test")
>>> g.send("learning python")
```

It seems that a yield expression perform as a functools.partial, excluding it should be primed  using next()

at this point, `def grep` is actually a `class grep`, because it initiate a generator object in first place.

The coroutine is tricky to follow, is my understanding on the right direction to continue without further side-effects since python named it `def` rather than `class` should has her reasons.

Comment: `type(grep)` is `function`, `type(grep('foo'))` is `generator`. I'm not sure what's the parallel you are seeing to `functools.partial`.

Comment: I guess in its implementation details it is a class. but is named a function with syntax consideration. @timgeb

Comment: @Sawajin well aren't you asking about implementation details? `grep` is an instance of `function` and `grep('foo')` is an instance of `generator`. If they were classes, they would be instances of `type` (or some metaclass).

Comment: For other readers: this questions seems to stem from David Beazley's [A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/) (see the slides)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that a yield expression perform as a `functools.partial`, [except that] it should be primed using `next()`.

I'm not sure what specifically makes you say that, but I don't immediately see the parallels.  `functools.parital` is designed to do parital binding of some args/kwargs to a callable and let you save some other args/kwargs to be called by the user.  ("`partial()` is used for partial function application which 'freezes' some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a new object with a simplified signature.")  That is not really what's going on with this generator, or any generator.

> The coroutine is tricky to follow, is my understanding on the right direction to continue without further side-effects since Python named it `def` rather than `class`?

They are tricky, agree with you there.  But I'm not sure if I'm seeing how a coroutine is "like a class in its nature."  A coroutine is a specialized generator.  Generators are defined with `def` and able to suspend and resume their execution.  That describes generators, not classes, and just replacing `def` with `class` would be syntactically invalid, for starters.

One way you can think of any expression like `a = yield b` is to **mark a break point.**

When you call `next(g)`, it will advance until it hits a `yield` statement, and stop there.  It will push the resulting value to the calling stack *but* it will suspend its execution and stop there, being resumable when you again call `next()` on it.  (This is the key difference between functions and generators, and between functions and coroutines, by extension.)

On the first call to `next()`, `line` is `None`.  (Basically, `line = yield None`.)  You will not be able to iterate over this because you can't say `for pattern in None`.  What "priming" means in this case probably refers to the fact that an initial call to `next(g)` is analogous to `g.send(None)`.

Now when you send additional values into the generator, they will be assigned to `line`, while `pattern` remains "python."  If "python" is found in whatever you `.send()` in, it gets printed.

```
>>> g = grep("python")
>>> n = g.send(None)  # equiv to next(g); stop at line = (yield)
Looking for python
>>> n is None
True
>>> g.send("coroutine test")
>>> g.send("coroutine test")
>>> g.send("coroutine test")  # no match
>>> g.send("learning python") # match
learning python
>>> g.send("python3.7") # match
python3.7
```

Comment: "What "priming" means in this case probably refers to the fact that an initial call to next(g) is analogous to g.send(None).", this insight light me up. thank you.

Comment: I think it analogy to a partial, because, g = grep(''python") freezed `python`  like g = functools.partial(grep, "python") if grep is defined as a standard function.

Comment: Okay, I sort of see what you're saying - but it doesn't really need to be "frozen" because `grep()` is only actually _called_ once.  After that, it stays entirely in the `while True` loop and `pattern` remains the same.  This is true of any function defined this way.